# Python numpy negative log likelihood calculation when some predicted probabilities are 1

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to calculate negative log likelihood.

I have a vector y of real labels. I have a vector p of estimated probabilities.

My NLL loss function is:

```
NLL = - y.reshape(len(y), 1) * np.log(p) - (1 - y.reshape(len(y), 1)) * np.log(1 - p)
```

Some of the probabilities in the vector p are 1. Therefore, some np.log(1 - p) are 0 and it gives me an error 
divide by zero encountered in log

How to get around this?

Please, help.

I have tried to do an if else work around so that

```
losslist = []
for i in range(y.shape[0]):
    if y[i] == 1:
        losslist.append(np.log(1 - p))
    else:
        losslist.append(np.log(p)) 
loss = np.array(losslist)
```

But it does not work either

Any suggestion welcome. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

Use `scipy.special.xlogy`. It treats zeros correctly:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy import special
>>>
>>> p = np.array([0.5, 0.1, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.9])
>>> y = np.array([0,   1,   0,   1,   1,   1  ])
>>> 
>>> -special.xlogy(y, p) - special.xlogy(1-y, 1-p)
array([ 0.69314718,  2.30258509, -0.        , -0.        ,         inf,
        0.10536052])
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you wrote `y[i] == 1` instead of `p[i] == 1`.

---

You can either use `np.where` to simulate an `if/else` statement or just replace the problem values:

```
v = y.reshape(len(y), 1)
NLL = -v * np.log(p) - (1 - v) * np.log(1 - p)
NLL[NLL == -np.inf] = 0
```

Replacing problem values has the added benefit that it works even for small values of `p`, e.g. `log(1e-324)`.

If you want to use a `np.where`:

```
v = y.reshape(len(y), 1)
NLL = np.where(1 - p == 0,
    -v * np.log(p) - (1 - v) * np.log(1 - p),
    0)
```